# What is the UTI for typescript .ts files?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, typescript

Is there any place where I can find the official [UTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Type_Identifier) string for TypeScript files?

I need to add it to my `Info.plist` in my Cocoa/Cocoa-touch App. I know I could easily add `com.microsoft.typescript` but I would rather add the official UTI for it :)

Any help is highly appreciated

PS: This is a [list of some UTI](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1)s declared in the system

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a UTI for it, as it's fairly recent. What exactly do you need to do with it?

Comment: I thought so, probably there is no official one yet ?. I just need it to declare (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_declare/understand_utis_declare.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319-CH204-SW1) that my app can read typescript files. Just that.

If there is no UTI yet, it would be nice if people at typescript project can suggest one.

Comment: for typescript there isn't a UTI and probably never will be since the extension .ts already is used for MPEG Layer 2 Transport Stream (UTI: public.mpeg-2-transport-stream) and there are some rumors about breaking things up if there are multiple UTIs for the same extension. source: https://github.com/n8gray/QLColorCode/blob/master/ReadMe.txt

Answer (score 1):

Unless the cost of change is too high, I recommend using your suggestion of `com.microsoft.typescript` until an official UTI is announced.